# Registration data not sent to mySQL database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a secure login with android but I have no way of testing it's functionality as the registration feature doesn't work. I have ensured I'm properly connected to the DB and I currently do not receive any errors.

### functions.php

This file contains functions for checking whether the user exists not, functions for generating password salt and hashes. I made use of random salt generator so that a unique salt and hash is generated for each user.

```
<?php
$random_salt_length = 32;

function userExists($username){
    $query = "SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = ?";
    global $con;
    if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    return false;
}

function getSalt(){
    global $random_salt_length;
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($random_salt_length));
}

function concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt){
    global $random_salt_length;
    if($random_salt_length % 2 == 0){
        $mid = $random_salt_length / 2;
    }
    else{
        $mid = ($random_salt_length - 1) / 2;
    }

    return
    substr($salt,0,$mid - 1).$password.substr($salt,$mid,$random_salt_length - 1);

}
?>
```

### register.php

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'db/db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) && isset($input['full_name'])){
    $username = $input['username'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $fullName = $input['full_name'];

    //Check if user already exist
    if(!userExists($username)){

        //Get a unique Salt
        $salt         = getSalt();

        //Generate a unique password Hash
        $passwordHash = password_hash(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //Query to register new user
        $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO member(username, full_name, password_hash, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$fullName,$passwordHash,$salt);
            $stmt->execute();
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "User created";
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    else{
        $response["status"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User exists";
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

### registerActivity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";
private EditText etUsername;
private EditText etPassword;
private EditText etConfirmPassword;
private EditText etFullName;
private String username;
private String password;
private String confirmPassword;
private String fullName;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String register_url = "http://10.0.0.1/members/register.php";
private SessionHandler session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.etConfirmPassword);
    etFullName = findViewById(R.id.etFullName);

    Button login = findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterLogin);
    Button register = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    //Launch Login screen when Login Button is clicked
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Retrieve the data entered in the edit texts
            username = etUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            confirmPassword = etConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            fullName = etFullName.getText().toString().trim();
            if (validateInputs()) {
                registerUser();
            }

        }
    });

}

// Display Progress bar while registering
private void displayLoader() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Signing Up.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

// Launch Dashboard Activity on Successful Sign Up
private void loadDashboard() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}

private void registerUser() {
    displayLoader();
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    try {
        //Populate the request parameters
        request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        request.put(KEY_FULL_NAME, fullName);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, register_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        //Check if user got registered successfully
                        if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                            //Set the user session
                            session.loginUser(username,fullName);
                            loadDashboard();

                        }else if(response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 1){
                            //Display error message if username is already existing
                            etUsername.setError("Username already taken!");
                            etUsername.requestFocus();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
}
```

### sessionHandler

```
public class SessionHandler {
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserSession";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_EXPIRES = "expires";
    private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
    private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public SessionHandler(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void loginUser(String username, String fullName) {
        mEditor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_FULL_NAME, fullName);
        Date date = new Date();

        //Set user session for next 7 days
        long millis = date.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        mEditor.putLong(KEY_EXPIRES, millis);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        Date currentDate = new Date();

        long millis = mPreferences.getLong(KEY_EXPIRES, 0);

        /* If shared preferences does not have a value
         then user is not logged in
         */
        if (millis == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        Date expiryDate = new Date(millis);

        /* Check if session is expired by comparing
        current date and Session expiry date
        */
        return currentDate.before(expiryDate);
    }

    public User getUserDetails() {
        //Check if user is logged in first
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            return null;
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(mPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setFullName(mPreferences.getString(KEY_FULL_NAME, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setSessionExpiryDate(new Date(mPreferences.getLong(KEY_EXPIRES, 0)));

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Logs out user by clearing the session
     */
    public void logoutUser(){
        mEditor.clear();
        mEditor.commit();
    }  
}
```

Can you please push me in the right direction as I can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong

Comment: What is the result of `$stmt->execute()`? It should return a boolean `true` or `false` to indicate success or failure

Comment: dont roll your own password hashing, its dangersous

Comment: @rickdenhaan no error message is displayed but I would assume that the result would fail  given unsuccessful registration

Answer (score 0):

If no error message is displayed but nothing is written to the database, it's possible your query is failing to execute.

This piece of code in `register.php` currently does not have any error checking:

```
//Query to register new user
$insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO member(username, full_name, password_hash, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$fullName,$passwordHash,$salt);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response["status"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "User created";
    $stmt->close();
}
```

This can fail in two places:

- `$con->prepare()` can fail if the database already knows the query won't be executed, e.g. due to a syntax error or because a table or column name doesn't exist or your user doesn't have the right permissions to perform an INSERT query into that table
- `$stmt->execute()` can fail if the query fails at runtime, e.g. if you're trying to insert a string into a column that only accepts integer values.

You should add some extra checks on that. At some point you will want to provide a useful error message to your app so users aren't confronted with technical mumbo-jumbo that they can't fix, but for now while debugging I'd recommend to dump the error message in there (it looks like a status of `> 1` indicates an error, correct me if I'm wrong):

```
//Query to register new user
$insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO member(username, full_name, password_hash, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$fullName,$passwordHash,$salt);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $response["status"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "User created";
    } else {
        $response["status"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->close();
} else {
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = $con->error;
}
```